# Map Markers overloading VM?

Tags: android, dictionary, bitmap, google-maps-markers

I have the following snippet in a database cursor while loop, so to see how many markers i can load into memory i removed cursor movetonext() and run it untill it overloads the VM, so using the .icon() i get approx 1060 markers and without i get about 160000, so what im wondering is that there is only 3 different bitmaps for all the markers, so do you have to load the bitmap for every marker or is there a more efficient way to do this, the amount of markers im going to need for the app is well over 1060, thank you for your time....

```
 marker = map.addMarker(new     MarkerOptions().position(latlng));//.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                     // .fromBitmap(knife)));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making a BitmapDescriptor for each bitmap of the three markers im going to use and then loading that when adding a marker solved this problem